# Grails SpringSecurity redirect from Apache to Tomcat doesn't work

Tags: apache, tomcat, grails, groovy, ajp

My app developed with Groovy & Grails (named MyApp) runs on Tomcat at 
`http://1.2.3.4:8080/MyApp`.
In the same server I have Apache that runs on port 80.
This app works fine.
I need to replace this Ip and port with myapp.example.com.

This is my Virtual Host in Apache:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName myapp.example.com
   ServerAlias *.myapp.example.com
   ProxyPass /MyApp !
   ProxyPass / ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/
   ProxyPassReverse / ajp://localhost:8009/MyApp/
   RedirectMatch 301 ^/MyApp/(.*)$ /$1
   RedirectMatch 301 ^/MyApp$ /
</VirtualHost>
```

With link `http://1.2.3.4:8080/MyApp` it's ok.

With link myapp.example.com MyApp starts fine, I show login page, but after login not works.
Only I recive this param in my browser:

```
myapp.example.com/?login_error=1
```

No messages, nothing...

I have updated Config.groovy in production section:

```
environments {
    development {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = true
    }
    production {
        grails.logging.jul.usebridge = false
        grails.serverURL = "http://myapp.example.com"
//      grails.plugins.springsecurity.portMapper.httpPort = "80"
//      grails.app.context="/MyApp"
        grails.app.context="/"
    }
}
```

With override port to 80, doesn't work.
With overide context to "/MyApp" don't work, with "/" don't work.

I use Grails 2.2.1 and SpringSecurity plugin for sign in.

Can you help me?
Thansk! ;)